# Automated Ubuntu 20.04 Template with GitLab CI/CD and vsphere-iso

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, packer, vsphere, ubuntu-20.04

Dear Community I need your help for understanding things.
I want to set up an automated Ubuntu 20.04 Template with a GitLab CI/CD in our vCenter.
So I configured a gitlab-runner with an own written packer Docker-Image (https://hub.docker.com/r/docker4bscg/packer) which should execute in the gitlab ci/cd my packer configs from the gitlab project. But the Problem now is, how do I expose the Packer HTTP Server which serves my cloud-init user-data/meta-data file? Or how do I make the subiquity config accessable via CI/CD over the Packer Gitlab Runner? Because the packer runs inside the Docker container, which got his own docker network.
Or is it possible to install a Ubuntu 20.04 Server via Packer with Subiquity where the user-data/meta-data are provided via floppy drive?
I hope you guys understand my question(s) and can help me solving it.

Greetings.